# Exceptions with if else statement in Scala

Tags: scala, if-statement, exception, databricks

```
if ( option != "AB" || option != "BC"|| option != "CD") {
  try {
    var option = dbutils.widgets.get("option")
  }

  catch {
  case e: Exception => println("The option shoud be following AB, BC or CD " + option)
}
}
```

I am trying to use exception in scala

However, the widget value is not throwing an exception when I use the value such as

"XY" or any other value than AB, BC or CD.

Please can someone let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thank you

Comment: ```if ( option != "AB" || option != "BC"|| option != "CD") {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("The option shoud be following AB, BC, CD" + option)
}``` used this but it does not takes AB and BC and CD as valid values

Comment: Show us the definiton of the first "option" variable used in the first if statement. And tell us where dbutils.widgets comes from or what it does.

Comment: your if statements `option != "AB" || option != "BC"|| option != "CD"` will always return true, Is this your expected behavior？

Comment: I would like to use AB, BC and CD as the options and prevent any other entry.

Answer (score 0):

If AB,BC & CD are the valid values, then your predicate should look like this:

```
if(option == "AB" || option == "BC" || option == "CD")
```

Also, you can use the `require` function to enforce the predicate and throw an exception if the input doesn't match:

```
def getWidget(option: String) = try {
  require(option == "AB" || option == "BC"|| option == "CD", s"The option shoud be following AB, BC or CD instead got $option")
  dbutils.widgets.get("option")
  } catch { case e: Exception => println(e) }
```